# I have got this matrix after training and testing two text datasets. How can I evaluate this output for cosine similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, cosine-similarity

```
1 0.070  0.208 0.038
0 0.030  0.690 0.908
0 0.303  0.90  0903
0 0.657  0.090 0.909
```

this is a matrix that I got after training and testing two text datasets. how can I use this for cosine similarity? I am not sure about the evaluation of the matrix.